# Unable to build project after updating firebase and Google service dpendency

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I updated all of my dependency library both in app and project level gradle file. Now whenever I am trying to build my project it showing error. While searching for the solution, got some tips from stackoverflow, but it didn't work. Below id my code for used in gradle files.

**Project Level gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.0'
    } }

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
        google()
    } }
```

**App level gradle dependency**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk'
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/'
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    google()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16

        targetSdkVersion 28

        versionCode 175
        versionName "3.6.7.5"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true

            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-project.pro'
            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-google-play-services.pro'
            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-apache.pro'
            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-crashlytics.pro'
            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-clevertap.pro'
            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-aws.pro'
            proguardFile '../proguard/proguard-mpandroidchart.pro'
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
        debug {
        }
        lintOptions {
            warning 'InvalidPackage'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        jumboMode = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'

    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.3.3'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.3'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.3.3'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.3.3'
    implementation 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.10'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'

    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.6"
    implementation files('libs/stickygridheaders.jar')
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_V2.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.4.0"
    //implementation 'in.juspay:ec-android-sdk:1.1.18'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'


    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Screen shot for the error message**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the dependencies that were updated?

Comment: Firebase, google service and also updated the compiled version to 28 from 27

Comment: The reason why you're facing those issues is that Firebase's Ads, AppIndexing, Cloud Messaging and Performance Monitoring library migrated to AndroidX from `18.0.0`, `19.0.0`, `18.0.0` and `18.0.0` respectively, which is the version that you're using. See the Firebase release notes for more info: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#update_-_june_17_2019

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this under `android` configuration part in your gradle file :

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Comment: I try adding this in gradle file. But after that when I try rebuilding my app, it got stuck, build process doesn't stop after 2-3 hours also. What will be the reason for that one?